# iterate row-wise through df to get ID numbers using str_locate_all in R

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

I'm looking to use the output of `str_locate_all` from the `stringr` package to find ID numbers. I know that the ID numbers will always be before the `.txt` but they won't necessarily be in the same position in the `key`.

Reproducible data frame is `df`

```
Key
a4pple//23.txt
ap5ples/24.txt
a6p////25.txt
a6p/25.txt
```

I'm looking for:

```
 ID
 23
 24
 25
 25
```

I'm thinking there's a straightforward way to do this using `dplyr` and `stringr` but I'm open to other approaches. My understanding of `lists` as an output from `stringr` is limiting my ability to solve this - any explanation of the lists syntax with a solution would be v appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

We can use `str_extract` from `stringr` to extract one or more numbers (`[0-9]+`) before a `.` and a 'txt' string

```
library(stringr)
df1$ID <- as.numeric(str_extract(df1$Key, "[0-9]+(?=\\.txt)"))
```

---

Or using `sub` from `base R`, capture the digits in a group (`([0-9]+)`) before the `.` and 'txt' string and replace it with the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
df1$ID <- as.numeric(sub(".*([0-9]+)\\.txt$", "\\1", df1$Key))
```

Comment: Wow - don't even need str_locate - v nice!

Answer (score 1):

Or a couple other options from `stringr`:

```
library(string)
str_extract(df$Key, "(?<=/)\\d+")
[1] "23" "24" "25" "25"

str_remove_all(df$Key, "^.*?/+|\\.txt")
[1] "23" "24" "25" "25"
```